# Вывести для каждой категории количество товаров MySQL

Tags: mysql

Как вывести список категорий, указывая для каждой категории количество товаров?

Таблица категорий:

```
idcategory int(11);
title varchar(255);
slug varchar(255);
```

Таблица продуктов:

```
idproduct(int11);
title varchar(255);
description text;
category_id int(11);
price decimal(19,2);
```

Comment: Эмм, а известен хоть примерный вид таблиц? Ну на вскидку: select category_name from table group by category_name

Comment: сгруппировать их по категориям, если грубо: `select group_name, count(1) as cnt from table_name group by group_name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  category_id as category,
  count(*) AS cnt
FROM
  таблица_продуктов
GROUP BY
  category_id
```

Можно ещё заджойнить таблицу категорий, чтоб получить описание категорий из неё.